# Toggle A Function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

***Problem***

My canvas image which was added through an API called FabricJS keeps getting removed when I try to clone it. I'm cloning it because I want to remove all the event listener in the canvas element.

***What I want***

Well what I want is to basically just be able to toggle on/off the straight line function which I can't do right now and that's exactly why I'm trying to clone it so I can remove all the event listeners. If you guys have any ideas of how to do this without cloning. All I have is the draw function but I can't toggle it at all.

***The Code***

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('base');
    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, { selectable: false});
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100});
    canvas.add(imgInstance, circle);
    var line, isDown;
    function cLine(run){
        if (run == false) {
            document.getElementById('c').removeEventListener('mousedown');
            document.getElementById('c').removeEventListener('mousemove');
            document.getElementById('c').removeEventListener('mouseup');
            return;
        } else {
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
        isDown = true;
        var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
        line = new fabric.Line(points, {
            strokeWidth: 2,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'red',
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
        });
            canvas.add(line);
        });

        canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
          if (!isDown) return;
          var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
          line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
          canvas.renderAll();
        });

        canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
          isDown = false;
        });
        }
    };

        function save() {
            if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
                alert('Sorry, your browser is not supported.');
            } else {
            canvas.deactivateAll();
            canvas.forEachObject(function(o){
                if(o.get("title") == "||Watermark||"){
                    canvas.bringToFront(o);
                }
            });
            window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'), "");
            canvas.forEachObject(function(o){
                if(o.get("title") == "||Watermark||"){
                    canvas.sendToBack(o);
                }
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
        }}
```

***WHAT I'm using***

I'm actually using FabricJS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to remove event handler, just handle it

```
var allowedToDraw = true; // the default value

function toggleDrawingLine(){
    allowedToDraw = !allowedToDraw;
}
```

and when drawing the line

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
    if (!isDown || !allowedToDraw){
        return;
    }
...
```

Comment: you'd better to add this check to other event handlers, namely `up` and `down`. But I thought of the same solution

Comment: Wow I didn't think of that... dang it! =P